# How to create a calendar (week view) component in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am in the process of creating a calendar component in Swing, and am running into some trouble.

I want the component to be able to be able to change amount of columns for different views, but that seems simple enough with GridBagLayout.

The problem is getting GBL to show a grid with row and columns that could be empty. I have tried, but can't get it to do that. What is a way to do this, or another simple method to end up being able to place panels on certain places on a grid, such as this:

[image: Weekly Calendar]

I have a class called PanelCalendarWeek that extends JPanel. Some of the code is omitted for brevity. The code is below, and the following link is a picture of its output.

[image: Layout Image]

```
public PanelCalendarWeek() {
    /* This panel holds the date */
    innerPanel = new JPanel();
    innerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    innerPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 700);
    innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
    innerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    /* Create Grid bag containts for the BLACK area */

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;

    /* Add example panels that would be dates */

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 2));
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 200));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    innerPanel.add(panel1, c);

    /* Create more components in the manner above for example reasons */

    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            innerPanel.setBounds(0, 0, columnView.getWidth(), 1000);
            innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(columnView.getWidth(), 1000));
        } // more code omitted for brevitu
    });

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setLayout(null);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(innerPanel);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);

    columnView = new JPanel();
    columnView.setBackground(Color.RED);
    columnView.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 50);
    columnView.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(columnView);

    rowView = new JPanel(); /* omitted, same process as above */

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: You have choices, you could use a `JTable` instead or you could create transparent "filler" objects which occupied each cell (or each cell was a `JPanel`, which onto you would add your events....)

Comment: You could draw the calendar as an image on a JPanel.